# Fast algorithms to approximate distance between two strings

Tags: string, algorithm, string-matching

I am working on a project that requires to calculate minimum distance between two strings. The maximum length of each string can be 10,000(m) and we have around 50,000(n) strings. I need to find distance between each pair of strings. I also have a weight matrix that contains the the weight for each character pairs. Example, weight between (a,a) = (a,b) = 0.

[image: weight matrix]

Just iterating over all pair of string takes O(n^2) time. I have seen algorithms that takes O(m) time for finding distance. Then, the overall time complexity becomes O(n^2*m). Are there any algorithms which can do better than this using some pre-processing? It's actually the same problem as auto correct.

Do we have some algorithms that stores all the strings in a data structure and then we query the approximate distance between two strings from the data structure? Constructing the data structure can take O(n^2) and query processing should be done in less than O(m).

> s1 = abcca, s2 = bdbbe

If we follow the above weighted matrix and calculate Euclidean distance between the two:

> sqrt(0^2 + 9^2 + 9^2 + 9^2 + 342^2)

**Context:** I need to cluster time series and I have converted the time series to [SAX](https://jmotif.github.io/sax-vsm_site/morea/algorithm/SAX.html) representation with around 10,000 points. In order to cluster, I need to define a distance matrix. So, i need to calculate distance between two strings in an efficient way.

Note: All strings are of same length and the alphabet size is 5.

https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs124/lec/med.pdf

http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=114

Comment: Is the the underlying alphabet fixed and if so, of what size? Please provide a more detailed example.

Comment: @Codor alphabet size is 5 and I have given an example.

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled about your estimation of the running time. I think calculation of the distance would be possible in `2n` steps, which would result in `O(n)`; where does the `O(n^2)` come from?

Comment: In the image you show the weights matrix is not symmetrical; then is it right that distance(A, B) may not be the same that distance(B, A)?

Comment: @jdehesa It's just an example. The matrix will be symmetrical.

Comment: @Codor O(n^2) time is for iterating over all pairs of strings and then calculating the distance between a pair takes O(m) time. n->total no of strings, m->size of each string

Comment: Do you really need this information? What's the larger problem you're trying to solve? Most of the times I've seen somebody go down this path, there was a more efficient way to solve their problem, that didn't include having to compute the edit distances among thousands of string pairs.

Comment: @JimMischel I have updated the details. See the context at the bottom

Comment: So are you trying to do sequence alignment, or are you looking for edit distance? With long strings and an alphabet size of five, I suspect you're doing sequence alignment.

Comment: @JimMischel I am doing sequence alignment as given as given https://jmotif.github.io/sax-vsm_site/morea/algorithm/SAX.html

Comment: If you need the distance for every pair of strings, the quadratic runtime bound cannot be improved upon because the number of values in the output is quadratic in the number of strings in the input.

Comment: @Codor Ya, I know that. I am asking about improving the distance calculation part.